# SQL SSIS New File Connection Outputting to Unix (LF) and UCS-2 LE BOM Encoding

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, encoding, ssis

I'm using SQL 2014 64 bit on Windows Server 2012R2.

Whenever I perform package level logging using a File Connection \ Create File (not flat file) it is creating a file in Unix (LF) and UCS-2 LE BOM Encoding.  I want it to be in Windows (CR LF) UTF-8 Encoding.

Why is this occurring?  I have checked all regional settings and they all point to UK\English

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Any chance you have NFS (Network File System) installed on your Windows Server?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else this is what worked in the end:

- Uninstalled all Visual Studio Shell instances
- Rebooted
- Installed SSDT for VS 2017